# Trying to concatenate values in Column C when A1 & B1 match A2 & B2

Tags: excel

I have three columns of data. Column A is a list of computers. Column B is the list of User ID's. Column C are the user permissions. What I want to do is concatenate the values in Column C when there is a match for A & B. Attached is a simple screenshot of what I am trying to do. Please advise the easiest way to achieve this. I am new to Excel formulas so any assistance is appreciated!

[image: Example]

Comment: And how would you like this to happen: vba or formula?  If Formula you will need to manually use Remove Duplicates on Column A and B to get the unique list.  Then you can use TEXTJOIN if you have Office 365 Excel.  If you do not have Office 365 Excel then most likely this will require vba.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Scott! I think I will have to use a VBA to get this completed. Do you have any tips as I've never used VBA in excel?

Also, I removed duplicates and have 997 unique values. Now i just need to add the duplicated values of A & B into column C.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired results don't make sense given your original data.

In particular, you only have two `bbb123` in your data, and the `aaa123` has two different matches.

If that is typo related, what you want can be done easily with `Power Query` aka `Get&Transform` which is a part of versions of Excel since 2010.

Except for the Custom Column, most of the code below can be generated automatically from the User Interface.

Algorithm:

- Group the data by machine and account
    -This forms a table of the grouped "permissions"
- Convert the `table` into a `list` (this is what the Custom Column does)
- Expand the list by extracting the values and using comma as the delimiter
- Delete the column containing the `table`s

The formula for the **custom column** is:  *(Add Column/Custom Column from the UI)*

```
=Table.Column([Grouped],"permissions")`
```

The M-Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"machine", type text}, {"account", type text}, {"permissions", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"machine", "account"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Column([Grouped],"permissions")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Grouped"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

### Original Data

[image]

### Grouped Data

[image]